induced drag at supersonic speed
for a delta wing with supersonic leading edge at small angle of attack there is no stagnation point on leading edge so There is no connection between the top and bottom of the wing. Therefore, the air cannot move from under to top of the wing .
does it means zero induced drag ? i mean leading edge vortex and wingtip vortex

This should answer your question.
